# Event Study Analysis in Stata

Tags: time-series, regression, stata

I want to evaluate the change in a numerical variable after a certain date.
I have different companies for which the event date is the same. The data looks approximately the following:

| Company | Date | Value | after_event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2020 | xx | 0 |
| 1 | 02-01-2020 | xx | 0 |
| 1 | 03-01-2020 | xx | 0 |
| 1 | 04-01-2020 | xx | 0 |
| 1 | 05-01-2020 | xx | 0 |
| 1 | 06-01-2020 | xx | 1 |
| 1 | 07-01-2020 | xx | 1 |
| 1 | 08-01-2020 | xx | 1 |
| 1 | 09-01-2020 | xx | 1 |
| 1 | 10-01-2020 | xx | 1 |
| 2 | 01-01-2020 | xx | 0 |
| 2 | 02-01-2020 | xx | 0 |
| 2 | 03-01-2020 | xx | 0 |
| 2 | 04-01-2020 | xx | 0 |
| 2 | 05-01-2020 | xx | 0 |
| 2 | 06-01-2020 | xx | 1 |
| 2 | 07-01-2020 | xx | 1 |
| 2 | 08-01-2020 | xx | 1 |
| 2 | 09-01-2020 | xx | 1 |
| 2 | 10-01-2020 | xx | 1 |

What I want to calculate is whether there was a change after the event date in the development of the values.

I would want to implement this in Stata and I came across the eventstudy, estudy, and eventstudy2 commands, however, I am not sure whether they are right for my case.

Can anyone help? I'm pretty new to Stata...

Comment: Did you try googling "event study analysis Stata"? This might be a good place to start: http://dss.princeton.edu/online_help...ventstudy.html. Without more context on what your use case is, what you've tried, what you hope to measure it's difficult for us to answer whether, for example, `estudy` is the right command for you.

Comment: Beyond the link above, I suggest you install the various commands you mentioned and read their help files. See https://www.stata.com/support/ssc-installation/. Then search `help` followed by the command name in the Stata console.